# I want my object to appear automatically without rising his scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my object to appear automatically without rising his scale, just to appear random places and not to collide with the coins (like to be superimposed). This is the Spawner for coins:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Object_Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject[] coins;

    private float coinSpawnTimer = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        coinSpawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (coinSpawnTimer < 0.01)
        {
            SpawnCoins();
        }
    }
    void SpawnCoins()
    {
        Instantiate(coins[(Random.Range(0, coins.Length))], new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + 30, Random.Range(2, 8), 0), Quaternion.identity);
        coinSpawnTimer = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.0f);
    } 
}
```

Comment: From the code it seems like there is a problem with the prefab, not the code.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the Unity Inspector for the prefab properties?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].